# C# - var to List<T> conversion

Tags: list, c#-3.0, var

How to cast/convert a var type to a List type?

This code snippet is giving me error:

```
List<Student> studentCollection = Student.Get();

var selected = from s in studentCollection
                           select s;

List<Student> selectedCollection = (List<Student>)selected;
foreach (Student s in selectedCollection)
{
    s.Show();
}
```

Comment: `var` is not a type, it's just a placeholder for the type of whatever expression you're assigning to the variable. In this case, the query expression evaluates to an `IEnumerable<Student>`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you do the Linq to Objects query, it will return you the type `IEnumerable<Student>`, you can use the [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method to create a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var selected = from s in studentCollection
                           select s;

List<Student> selectedCollection = selected.ToList();
```

Comment: This answer has a better explanation than my own. This should be accepted.

Comment: @CMS hi my friend. I tried this solution in my project's smilar problem. It didn't work for me. Can you help me for this question?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839483/how-can-change-list-type

Answer (score 8):

The `var` in your sample code is actually typed as `IEnumerable<Student>`. **If all you are doing is enumerating it, there is no need to convert it to a list**:

```
var selected = from s in studentCollection select s;

foreach (Student s in selected)
{
    s.Show();
}
```

If you do need it as a list, the [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method from Linq will convert it to one for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the ToList LINQ extension Method

```
List<Student> selectedCollection = selected.ToList<Student>();
foreach (Student s in selectedCollection)
{
    s.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
List<Student> selectedCollection = selected.ToList();
```